# How to interpret parasolid x_t file in order create an importer in Java

Tags: java, format, cad

Am trying to create an importer to import a parasolid x_t file in order to convert it to another format. I have tried to understand the "Parasolid XT Format Reference" documented and its explanation of the parasolid x_t format but with no luck.

Can anyone give a clear example or point me towards one?

I would also settle with a library which can do it for me.

Answer (score 2):

I am implementing my own one right now.

You should read veeeeery carefully the reference document and get a schema file (e.g. sch_13006.s_t).
What I've done so far is reading the schema file into memory and now I'm generating the source code of the reader for that particular schema. Which schema to use is in the headers of the XT file. I'm struggling a bit with the lists and other things but it's my second day doing it so I have just started. ;)

This is not an easy task at all. After reading the content of the XT file itself, the most dificult part of the task starts... what to do with that bunch of data. =P

Good luck.

Comment: I have done it :)
At least for the schemas I've got: 19008, 13006, 12006
I have to get 26105. If you have it, I would really appreciate if you could point me to it.
The other schemas... I have found them very easily on the internet. Google has got the answer to "almost" all out question :)

Comment: Great to hear you figured alot of it out. Unfortunately we decided, for our needs, it was good enough to create an IGES exporter and so we did. Sorry I don't know where 26105 schema would be. Good luck though.

Comment: I should note we contacted the guys that support parasolid format at Siemens. They offer, at some price, an interoptiblity engine that can import export parasolids and much more. Also, by the sounds of it the reference manual is not maintained and really isn't meant to be guide to create importers and the alike.